# Close ui-bootstrap modal with mouse click with no backdrop

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm currently migrating ui-bootstrap from 0.5.0 to 0.14.3 (yep, I haven't checked for updates for that long). In 0.5.0 there was a 'modal' directive with the 'options' config object. There was a 'backdropClick' option, which allowed the modal to be closed when mouse-clicked outside of it. In 0.14.3 the $uibModal service doesn't have such option. It has a 'backdrop' property, which could be set to 'static', allowing you to close the modal with a mouse click, but the modal has a backdrop. And what if it hasn't? Could I close it with a mouse click with 'backdrop' property set to 'false'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround for this missing feature.
You can use a directive to detect a "click outside" event and then in the related event call the close modal method.

In the example below (adapted from ui.bootstrap docs) I used [angular-click-outside directive](https://github.com/IamAdamJowett/angular-click-outside):

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap','angular-click-outside']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModal, $log, $document) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.animationsEnabled = true;
  
  $document.on('click', function(event) {
    
  });

  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      backdrop: false,
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };

  $scope.toggleAnimation = function () {
    $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
  };

});

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $uibModal service used above.

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, items) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.0.3.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//rawgit.com/IamAdamJowett/angular-click-outside/master/clickoutside.directive.js"></script>
    
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
      <div id="my-modal" click-outside="cancel()">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                    <a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </script>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('lg')">Large modal</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('sm')">Small modal</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="toggleAnimation()">Toggle Animation ({{ animationsEnabled }})</button>
    <div ng-show="selected">Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```